# Why verbose php code tokens?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, tags

Something I can't understand while seeing the verbose `phtml` templates:

Why the short tag and usual code tokens aren't used in Magento ?

`<?= $content ?>` instead of `<?php echo $content ?>`

or:

```
<? if ($condition) { ?>
<? } ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php if ($condition): ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

that would clear a bit those template files IMHO.

Comment: Because there are not recommended, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use you can read some reasons why.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I just skimmed the answers, and  seems like in current PHP version it's more likely to use it. Glad that this was discussed. The only issue is a search and replace in entire Magento.

Comment: Heh, I always like non-standard code where I can't diff against the original. <grin> I've been where shortcuts take hours and miles longer than the original route.

Comment: I concur @FiascoLabs this is common in Magento development. That's why you also have to think like merchant, i.e. use features instead of coding everything.

Answer (score 1):

PHP short tags `<?` are only valid if php.ini has `short_open_tag` enabled.  This can cause problems when moving code from one server that supports them to another server that doesn't.  In general, it's good practice to always use the full `<?php` tag.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: Well, a comment above led me to the stackoverflow discussion about this. So, the only reason I see for not doing the search and replace is compatibility with Magento updates.